# How to call soap service about a millon times from JMeter using data from a CSV file

Tags: csv, soap, jmeter

I have to take inputs from a CSV file which has a comma separated single line of million 6 character strings. I need to read these one by one and run the JMeter SOAP post query by attaching these values

What I need to know is how to configure this csv file to read data one by one and pass it to the SOAP query. I tried adding a CSV option with a while controller in JMeter. But doesnt seem to work. I need to know the condition in the while controller as well.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using following Test Plan configuration:

- Test Plan

  - Thread Group

    - While Controller
    - Counter
    - SOAP Post Query

      - CSV Data Set Config

Relevant configuration:

[While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

- Condition: `${__javaScript(${N}<1000000)}`

[Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter)

- Start: `1`
- Increment: `1`
- Maximum: `1000000`
- Reference Name: `N`

[SOAP/XML-RPC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request)

- everything as per your current use case

[CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)

- Recycle on EOF: `true`
- Stop thread on EOF: `false`

Answer (score 1):

For my scenario, it didn't require any while controller.
I've done following Test Plan configuration with JMeter 2.9 & JDK 1.6:

- Test Plan

  - Thread Group

    - SOAP/XML-RPC Request

      - CSV Data Set Config

**Thread Group:**

```
Number of Threads: <as per your requirement>
Ramp-Up Period (in seconds): <as per your requirement>
Loop Count: 1
```

**SOAP/XML-RPC Request:**

```
URL: http://<The WSDL of your web service>?wsdl
Send SOAPAction: <name of action to be performed>
Soap/XML-RPC Data:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fac="<your URL>">
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fac:abc>
         <arg0>
            <var1>${var1}</var1>
            <var2>${var2}</var2>
         </arg0>
      </fac:abc>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**CSV Data Set Config:**

```
Filename: xyz.csv
Variable Names (comma-delimited): var1,var2
Delimiter: ,
Stop Thread on EOF: True
Sharing mode: All threads
```

Other parameters as per your requirement.
CSV file should be in the same folder where you have saved Test Plan. Otherwise, you need to specify relative path.

**xyz.csv:**

```
123,456
789,111
222,333
```